# Equivalent of Chef's templates in Glu

Tags: templates, deployment, configuration, chef-infra

[Templates in Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Templates) works great for generating configuration files - you have templating engine for creating the files, and you can pass parameter at multiple levels - default, role-based, node.

Is there anything like that for the deployment automation platform [glu](https://github.com/linkedin/glu)?

The only thing similar I could find, is [this example](https://github.com/linkedin/glu/blob/master/scripts/org.linkedin.glu.script-jetty/src/main/groovy/JettyGluScript.groovy) of setting-up jetty. If you look at the end of the script, you'll see some multi-line strings, which are used as file contents for specific files. This could work, but seems somewhat messy, and I was hoping for a better way.

Comment: Proposed new tag `linkedin-glu`. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133044/existing-tag-with-the-name-as-my-desired-one-but-for-different-thing for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glu does not have any built-in template mechanism.

That being said, like you point out in the example, you can use the `shell.saveContent()` api which allows you to replace `@xxx@` values automatically. The "String" that you replace does not have to be inside the glu script itself and can simply be read from a url by using the `shell.cat(url)` api.

If you want to be more sophisticated, a glu script is simply written in groovy so you can use the templating mechanism that comes with groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates